# Encrypting shared preference data

Tags: android, encryption

I have been using encryption for storing data in shared preference. The existing encryption mode uses static hard coded encryption key along and ECB mode. My app is live in the google play store. As per the security audit report, i need to remove using hard coded encryption key and replace with dynamic secret key. Also i need to enhance my encryption mode from ECB to CBC, which i am able to do successfully. But the problem is my playstore build has different encryption mode and key, so now when i try update the existing app with the new encryption key and mode, all my shared preference data is lost while decryption. Kindly suggest how can i handle updating existing user smoothly with the new encryption logic.

Comment: Decrypt it with the old key, re-encrypt it with the new technique

Comment: Can you first decrypt SharedPreferences and then encrypt with the new key?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/security/data